# not getting response from url in android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which I have 5 items in a listview. I am not able to fetch my data in the listview,...I have tried all things,,,but nothing is dere in the listview

My url is

http://harpreetvir.web708.discountasp.net/PMevents/XmlRecord/AddEvent.xml

My ddms logcat is http://pastebin.com/YH0JWiRJ

Can anyone do the help?

Comment: My xml handler java class is pastebin.com/4D0J1A5x My java file code is pastebin.com/vvbeAR0s –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly go through the following code posted.

```
      try {
           HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
           String postURL = "http://harpreetvir.web708.discountasp.net/PMevents/XmlRecord/AddEvent.xml";
           HttpGet post = new HttpGet(postURL);
           HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
           HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();  
           String str1=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
           str1=str1.trim();
           parsing(str1);
      } 
      catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      public void parsing(String str1) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException{
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        xpp.setInput( new StringReader (str1));
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
         String str;
         if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
            System.out.println("Start document");
         } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
             str    =   xpp.getName();
             System.out.println("Start tag "+str);

         } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
             System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
         } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
             System.out.println("Value= "+xpp.getText());
         }
         eventType = xpp.next();
        }
       System.out.println("End document");
    }
```

Comment: this code should i write my myxml handler class....what about logscreen java class code,,,how is it ? have u seen it

Comment: @user956329 This code should be written on the class where you want to show the list, this is using the webservices to fetch the values so better use the Threading concept: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html to fetch the data from the server

Comment: i have added my logscreen1 java class,,,,there i will add this,,,,this code if for parsing data ??

Comment: @user956329 No I don't have skype installed... What I normally following is that, I will create separate class for parsing all the webservices... like WebSeviceParsing.java and do all the parsing of the application on that dedicated class...

Comment: @brasil if u install skype,,it will be better,,,,i have done parsing in 1 class and setlistview in other class,,